# angular 2 app on ios does not display bound data properly

Tags: ios, angular

Our angular 2 app does not display data on iphone 4s(ios 9.3.5) devices.

Tried  Safari,Firefox and Chrome.Still No luck.

All browsers on android display the app. like a charm.

I'd like the app to display the data on iphone devices properly.

Below the first screenshot shows the app running on an iphone 4s.

Style is there but there are no numbers.

The desired outcome is in the second screenshot where the user can display numeric values properly on an android device.
Any Help is appreciated.

kind regards.

[image: iphone 4 no data is displayed]

[image: android device data displayed correctly]

Android device - data is displayed correctly

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Polsan</title>
  <base href=".">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./res/images/favicon.ico">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
    crossorigin="anonymous">


  <!-- application css -->
  <link href="./res/styles/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.ywxi.net/js/1.js" async></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.4.1/es5-shim.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.33.3/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.20/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <app-root>Uygulama Yükleniyor...</app-root>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: only stuck on iphone series 4. no issues reported on iphone5&6 family.

Comment: please help. We are indeed struggling

Comment: problem  is missing the intl polyfill.  <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl.~locale.en"></script>